# How to set transparent background for richtextbox using the WPF RichTextBoxToolBar Control?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, richtextbox

I am using the WPF `RichTextBoxToolBar` control from [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/448062/WPF-RichTextBoxToolBar-Control) Code Project project, combined with the `Exteneded WPF Toolkit`'s `RichTextBox` control.

When I enter text for the first time with no formatting it's all ok and the background is `Transparent`. But when I use the toolbar to set the background to `Transparent` it actually sets it to `White`. I've noticed the additional `\highlight1` parameter in the RTF format of the text which does this thing.

Does anyone have experience with this toolbar? Is there a way to change this behavior? Can I disable the background color picker command?

Following is the code of a small test project I made to investigate this. The project only needs to install the `Extended WPF Toolkit` from NuGet and reference the dll from [this zip](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/448062/RichTextBoxToolBarBin.zip).

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="RtbTest.MainWindow" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:rtb="clr-namespace:RichTextBoxToolBar;assembly=RichTextBoxToolBar"
        xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.xceed.com/wpf/xaml/toolkit" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <DockPanel>
        <rtb:RichTextBoxToolBar Margin="0,0,0,5" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Name="EditTextToolbar" />

        <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Content="Save RTF text" Click="ShowRtfText"/>
            <Button Content="Reload RTF text" Click="ReloadRtfText"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <toolkit:RichTextBox Name="EditTextRtb">
            <toolkit:RichTextBox.TextFormatter>
                <toolkit:RtfFormatter />
            </toolkit:RichTextBox.TextFormatter>
        </toolkit:RichTextBox>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Codebehind:

```
namespace RtbTest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ShowRtfText(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(EditTextRtb.Text);
        }

        private void ReloadRtfText(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string rtfText;

            rtfText = EditTextRtb.Text;
            EditTextRtb.Text = rtfText;
        }
    }
}
```